# Remove unpopulated UITableViewCells?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Working with TableViews and have a two-parted question:

1. I have a TableView where there are only four cells with content. However the TableView continues down with about five or six more, empty, cells. Is there a way of removing these? What this would do, graphically, is remove all the lines below these 4 cells, while everything else stays the same.

Regard the following image, it has 2 populated cells and 7 extra lines below them, I want theses lines removed:

[image]

2.The four cells contain buttons. Because of this I want to remove the users ability to click/mark the entire cell. Is there such a "setting"?

Thank you, Tobias Tovedal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking of 2 ways to accomplish your first Q:

- Set up TableView to be grouped and not plain (tableview will have round corners);
- Make the separators color to match the background of the cells:

> ```
> tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];// or whatever color you have
> ```

But you will have to manually add a line for each cells you are displaying.

Comment: I like the second solution best. Is it possible to define the color of the lines individually? So I can make the ones I want a solid grey color.

Comment: Im starting to think this isn't possible in any other way than what you've described. I solved it by setting a background image to the cells, which have a slight bevel, that gives sort of the effect I want.

Comment: You're better off just removing the cells by nilling the footer

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}
```

2.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: 2. `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;`

Comment: 1. - I use these methods in the way you describe, however the effect is still the same. I'll edit my questions with some pictures to clearify. 2. - This doesn't seem to do the trick eigther...

Comment: @Bartek! `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;` solved my second question, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set 0 to the size of your footer to clear those "ghost" cells.

```
self.myTable.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Simple and straight +1 @Departamento B